# using isintance on a pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I am expecting multiple data types as input to a function & want to take a specific action if its a pydantic model (pydantic model here means `class StartReturnModel(BaseModel)`).
In case of model instance I can check it, using `isinstance(model, StartReturnModel)` or `isinstance(model, BaseModel)` to identify its a pydantic model instance.
Based on the below test program I can see that `type(StartReturnModel)` returns as  `ModelMetaclass`.  **Can I use this to identify a pydantic model?** or is there any better way to do it?

```
from pydantic.main import ModelMetaclass
from typing import Optional

class StartReturnModel(BaseModel):
    result: bool
    pid: Optional[int]

print(type(StartReturnModel))
print(f"is base model: {bool(isinstance(StartReturnModel, BaseModel))}")
print(f"is meta model: {bool(isinstance(StartReturnModel, ModelMetaclass))}")

res = StartReturnModel(result=True, pid=500045)
print(f"\n{type(res)}")
print(f"is start model(res): {bool(isinstance(res, StartReturnModel))}")
print(f"is base model(res): {bool(isinstance(res, BaseModel))}")
print(f"is meta model(res): {bool(isinstance(res, ModelMetaclass))}")

*****Output****
<class 'pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass'>
is base model: False
is meta model: True

<class '__main__.StartReturnModel'>
is start model(res): True
is base model(res): True
is meta model(res): False
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. `BaseModel` is just a class like any other. It happens to have a more specialized metaclass, but instance and subclass checks still work like with any other class. Why would you check against the metaclass, if all you need is to identify a specific class? If you need to check, if the class you have at hand inherits from `BaseModel`, just use `issubclass`. If you have an _instance_ and want to check that, just use `isinstance`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it, but why not use `isinstance` or `issubclass`.

Comment: pydantic docs didn't talk about such a usage. Wanted to know if there was any catch to the usage. Also ModelMetaclass looked more an internals of pydantic & wasn't sure if I can use in application? Also `issubclass(StartReturnModel, ModelMetaclass)`  returns `False` from the above example. So I am left with isinstance only I guess.

Comment: @vsnag Why would the docs talk about that? There is nothing special here in Pydantic. There is no need for the metaclass to be involved in your checks. And `issubclass(StartReturnModel, ModelMetaclass)` correctly returns `False`. It would return `True`, if you replaced `issubclass` with `isinstance`. From your question and comment is starting to seem as though you just don't fully understand Python classes and metaclasses in general.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg If you revisit my example walk through the outputs, I am trying to use isinstance on Model itself & not the Model instance. I am particular about the 1st 3 print statements in the above example. Last four print statements are obvious & are very well documented in pydantic (https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#basic-model-usage).
Also `ModelMetaclass` is imported from pydantic. Hence I wanted to know if the usage is correct.

Comment: @vsnag Not sure what you are trying to tell me because none of those checks (`isinstance` or `issubclass` for entire models) are even mentioned in the docs you linked and neither should they. The question remains, **why** you so desperately want to use `isinstance` instead of just using `issubclass(StartReturnModel, BaseModel)`.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg input to the function can be either a pydantic Model itself or a pydantic model instance. Based on the type of the input I want to take some specific actions. It would have rather better If I would have asked the question as, is there way to differentiate between pydantic model & model instance?

Comment: "is there way to differentiate between pydantic model & model instance", yes - like any class vs instance check, the easiest way is to use `isinstance(thing, type)`

Answer (score 1):

After you expanded a bit in the comment thread, it is clear that you have a fundamental gap in understanding of Python classes and metaclasses. The topics have been discussed at length on SO, so I'll just refer you to the search function for details, but the short answer to your particular question is this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.main import ModelMetaclass


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: str


obj = MyModel(x=1, y="a")
cls = MyModel

print(f"{isinstance(obj, BaseModel)=}")
print(f"{isinstance(obj, MyModel)=}")
print(f"{issubclass(cls, BaseModel)=}")
print(f"{issubclass(cls, MyModel)=}")
print(f"{cls is MyModel=}")
print(f"{isinstance(cls, ModelMetaclass)=}")  # just to illustrate
print(f"{isinstance(cls, type)=}")            # just to illustrate
```

Output:

```
isinstance(obj, BaseModel)=True
isinstance(obj, MyModel)=True
issubclass(cls, BaseModel)=True
issubclass(cls, MyModel)=True
cls is MyModel=True
isinstance(cls, ModelMetaclass)=True
isinstance(cls, type)=True
```

You should avoid using `pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass` because it is currently not (fully) exposed publicly as you correctly noted. And as you can see from the code above, there is simply no need to deal with it for you.

If you have a function that is supposed to handle both *instances* of a model class and specific *classes* that inherit from `BaseModel`, that could look like this:

```py
from typing import Union
from pydantic import BaseModel


def do_stuff(obj_or_cls: Union[BaseModel, type[BaseModel]]) -> None:
    if isinstance(obj_or_cls, BaseModel):
        print(f"Got an instance of the model `{obj_or_cls.__class__.__name__}`")
    elif isinstance(obj_or_cls, type) and issubclass(obj_or_cls, BaseModel):
        print(f"Got a model subclass called `{obj_or_cls.__name__}`")
    else:
        raise TypeError


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: str


obj = MyModel(x=1, y="a")
cls = MyModel


do_stuff(obj)
do_stuff(cls)
```

Output:

```
Got an instance of the model `MyModel`
Got a model subclass called `MyModel`
```